# Create animation similar to AppBar

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm trying to create an animation similar to the AppBar - basically make a control come in from the bottom edge of the screen. The problem with this is that the height of the control can change depending on its content, so I can't set an initial `TranslateTransform.Y` value in the XAML or in the Loaded event because the contents get generated AFTER the page is loaded.

So, in other (and fewer) words. I need to animate a control for which I don't know its size into the screen. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check WinRT XAML Toolkit's CustomAppBar for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Transition.
E.g. PaneThemeTransition or EntranceThemeTransition.
I'm not sure which property you should use to add a transition because it depends on your case. But you can do something like this:

```
Popup.ChildTransitions = new TransitionCollection { new EntranceThemeTransition() };
```

The Popup is not mandatory:

```
<uielement>
  <uielement.Transitions>
    oneOrMoreTransitions
  </uielement.Transitions>
</uielement>
```

[Animations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh452703.aspx)